# Do I need a comma when addressing someone in writing?

Tags: commas

When I'm addressing someone in writing, such as on a forum or other public space, will I need a comma(s) before/after/surrounding their name?

For example:

> Thanks for that information **Greg** we're here to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Chicago Manual of Style’s FAQ on commas](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0008.html), a comma should be used before a name, title or term of endearment when that person is directly addressed:

> **[I]n formal writing, direct address takes a comma before the person’s name**. One could argue, however, that e-mails aren’t formal, and that there’s little harm in streamlining for the sake of efficiency

If the name is not the last word in the sentence then a comma should follow it also.

Thus, if your example was retained as a single sentence it would be:

> Thanks for that information, Greg, we're here to help.

Having said that, this would read more smoothly if expressed as two sentences:

> Thanks for that information, Greg. We're here to help.

Comment: Here's a reference to consider adding to your answer: [CMoS online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas.html) "*in formal writing, direct address takes a comma before the person’s name*" (search for "Hi, Mom" on the page and click its 'Answer>>' link).

Comment: With a period it reads less comma-splicy :)

Comment: Hi, the I edited the quote from Chicago directly into your answer, as SE prefers answers stand alone and cite material from links, in case an important link stops working one day. But of course it is your answer, so feel free to roll back or otherwise re-edit.